# Unban everyone command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have made this code for unbanning everyone. But it is not working. What is wrong in this? I am a beginner.

```js
let discord = require("discord.js")
let client = new discord.Client()

client.on('message', message => {
  const member = message.member;
  switch (message.content.toLowerCase()) {
    case (PREFIX + "-unban all"):
      if (member.hasPermission('MANAGE_SERVER')) {
        async function ubAll() {
          const users = await message.guild.fetchBans()
          for (const user of users.array()) {
            await message.guild.unban(user)
          }
        }
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("Done!")
          .setDescription("Successfully Unbanned everyone.")
          .setColor("Green")
          .setThumbnail("https://riyazapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/checkmark.gif")

      }
      if (!member.hasPermission('MANAGE_SERVER')) {
        message.reply("You do not have enough permissions for this command!")
      }
  }
})

client.login("not showing")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
  const member = message.member;
  switch (message.content.toLowerCase()) {
    case ("-unban all"):
      if (member.hasPermission('MANAGE_SERVER')) {
        async function ubAll() {
            let users = await message.guild.fetchBans();
            let userArr = users.array();
            let unbanUsers = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < userArr.length; i++) {
                unbanUsers.push(userArr[i].user.id);
            }
            for(var j = 0; j < unbanUsers.length; j++) {
                message.guild.members.unban(unbanUsers[j]);
            }
        }
        ubAll();
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("Done!")
          .setDescription("Successfully Unbanned everyone.")
          .setColor("Green")
          .setThumbnail("https://riyazapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/checkmark.gif")
        message.channel.send(embed);

      }
      else {
        message.reply("You do not have enough permissions for this command!")
      }
      break;
  }
})

client.login("not showing")
```

Hello, there were many mistakes in your code. You have used `PREFIX` without defining it. I guessed your prefix is `-` as I saw it in the first case of your switch-case. Anyways I also fixed your `ubAll` function. It looks a bit more complicated now, but don't worry it's not that hard to understand. As I'm a fan of classic for-loops, I used them in the new function.

**So what does the function?**
In `users` all the information from the banned users are stored. In `userArr` we simply store all the information we get from `users` in an array. Then I've created an empty array `unbanUsers` were we would like to store all the users we would like to unban (everyone in our case). Then in the first for-loop we iterate throug all values in our `users` array and push the users ID's into our `unbanUsers` array (because we need the ID of a user to unban him). Now the ID's from every user we found in the first for-loop are stored in `unbanUsers`. In the second for-loop, we iterate throug our `unbanUsers` array and unban every user.

Then you have to call the function, because if you don't do that, it simply can't work. You also forgot the `break;` in your case. For every case in a switch-case you need a `break;`, because otherwise it will search until he finds the first `break;` and if there is no one it will create an endless loop. And at the and you have to send the embed you've created into the channel.